# Tool to compare and merge files in different folders

Tags: netbeans, merge, comparison, diff

I am developing two Java based projects that are very similar which means that what i do to the first one i can use diff to... command in Netbeans to apply the changes to the second one. However there is a problem with the images folder. For example i work one week on the first project and during this week i put 34 new images in the images directory. Then i have to put some of this images in the images directory of the second project. Copy/paste is not a solution because the projects are NOT EXACTLY THE SAME.

That is why i need you to recommend me some tool that can show me which pictures are missing in the seconds directory so i can simply drag them to their new location:)

Answer (score 2):

`diff -rq <path1> <path2>` will give you a list of files that are only in one of the paths, as well as an indication of whether file names that exist in both actually have the same content.